# How do you create a toolbar like StumbleUpon to load other pages?

Tags: javascript, iframe

*not a browser extension

Here are a couple of example sites that do it: http://www.thecollegecartel.com/
and of course: http://www.stumbleupon.com/

Here is an example of the toolbar in action: http://www.thecollegecartel.com/out.php?pid=138339&type=next

Answer (score 1):

If you are not developing a browser extension and you want the toolbar to live inside your app  then you will need to pull the sites into an iframe.

Here is a VERY rough snippet that has not been tested, just to get you started

```
...
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function changePage() {
         //fetch the next page url from somewhere
         document.getElementById('frame').src = 'some/new/page.html';
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toolbar">
 <a id="fetchNextPage" href="javascript:changePage()" >next</a>
</div>


<iframe id="frame" src="firstPage.html" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```